# My stylesheet will not link with my html

Tags: html, css

I put the link into all of my html pages and my css only shows up on my first page but none of the others.

```
<head>
    <title>Angels Drawings</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <STYLE>
    <!--
    A{text-decoration:none}
    -->
    </STYLE>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Angel</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li><a href="Pages/Page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="Pages/Page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2>This is her website</h2>
    <p>And this is all the info</p>

</body>
```

Comment: Try `href="/style.css"`

Comment: http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other pages (Page2.html and Page3.html) are inside the "Pages" directory. You cannot use the same url for the css because it is a relative path. That means it will try to find the css into the "Pages" directory, and it will fail because it doesn't exist.

Answer updated after discussing the real use case with the OP.

In the `Angelswebsite.html` use the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

In all pages inside the `Pages` subdirectory use the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
```

Comment: I tried using that solution and it did not work either, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Can you show me the file structure of your website?

Comment: I have a folder on my desktop called "Angels Website", inside of that is a folder called "HTML". Within the HTML folder are 2 other folders named "Pages" and "Images" as well as Angelswebsite.html and styles.css

Comment: sorry if i explained it poorly, I am kind of new to this stuff, especially html and css.

Comment: Ok, and which folder is the root of your website? Are you running your website into a proper web server, or are you just opening the .html file with your browser?

Comment: The root of the website is in the HTML folder, i am running it with my browser

Comment: Ok, that's the problem. The root of your website if you open the .html file like that is the root of your hard disk (to be more precise, the root of the hard disk partition where that .html is stored). So, you cannot use "/style.css" as a path. Instead, use a relative path which points to the style.css file located into the parent directory. `href="../style.css"`. Note: this is only valid for pages 2 and 3, which are the ones located into the "Pages" subdirectory.